# Can the Gradle Eclipse Plugin attach source jar files to local jar dependencies

Tags: eclipse, gradle

If I have maven dependency in Gradle then the eclipse plugin will automatically download the source jar file if there is one and attach it in the generated eclipse ".classpath" file.

Is is possible to get a similar behaviour for local file depencies (that I have the source jar of)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a flatDir repository, the Eclipse plugin should attach any source jars as long as they are in the same location as the dependency jar (with the same name followed by either -src or -sources).

Say you have a local jar called `dependency.jar` at location `x/y/z`. If you put the sources jar in the same location and call it `dependency-sources` or `dependency-src`, it will be attached.

Please note that this only works for flatDir repositories and not for plain file dependencies.

Comment: This might work when using a `flatDir` repository (unsure). It won't work when using plain `file` dependencies. It should be possible to replace the latter with the former, though.

Comment: Yes that is the solution I was looking for! Ich changed my plain file dependency to a dependency in a flatDir. Then the eclipse plugin will find the sources jar. Thank you!